# Ubuntu Docker server limited to 114 containers

Tags: docker, .net-core

I currently have 114 .Net Core 2.2 API containers running on an Ubuntu 20.04 server. When I add a new container, the container immediately shuts down with Exit Code 0 and no messages to stdout. If I stop a previously running container, the new container works but the one I stopped will not restart - same Exit Code 0 and no messages to stdout. Basically, all of the containers work but only 114 at a time.

For the time being, I've chosen one of the "less critical" containers to experiment with.

What I've tried:

I've added a Console.Writeline as the first line of Main in Program.cs and changed the ENTRYPOINT to /bin/bash and tried running the "dotnet" command manually. After a few seconds it just returns to the command prompt with no output (the Writeline never gets executed).

I've used **docker inspect** to examine the container after it stops and it doesn't appear to be OOMKilled.

I've used **docker logs** to display the log but it shows nothing.

I've also increased the **fs.inotify.max_user_watches** from 8192 to 16384 with no change.

Memory or CPU doesn't seem to be an issue:
[image]

Here is my docker info

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does an ENTRYPOINT of `bash echo hi` work? If so, I would try an strace on dotnet. Something like `ENTRYPOINT strace -fo strace.log dotnet /rest/of/your/dotnet/command/and/args`. Then grab the `strace.log` from the container (maybe direct it to a volume you can access outside of the container too?).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@omajid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3561275/omajid)'s comment I was finally able to get at least some kind of error returned.

The error was:
"The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached".

The fix was to increase the number of **max_user_instances** by executing:

**sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256**

Comment: What does your `ENTRYPOINT` command look like now? Are you using `dotnet run`?

Comment: Yes...After changing the max_user_instances I was able to go back to my "regular" ENTRYPOINT.
(From docker inspect)
        "Entrypoint": [
            "dotnet",
            "dllName.dll"
        ],